# Drawing lines and points in 3D space still impossible with pure WPF?

Tags: wpf, 3d, drawing, lines, points

I've read few (old) posts and tutorials about drawing lines and points in WPF 3D.

They all say, that its impossible in pure WPF, and I have to use 3D Tools.

Has anything changed in that matter? (I mean .NET versions released after 3.0/3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is still no support in WPF 3D for proper lines and points in 3D scenes. WPF 3D has not gotten much love in recent versions.

However, you might want to have a look at the [Helix Toolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com), which is a great set of helpers and controls for WPF 3D, including support for screen-space points and lines (improved from the 3D Tools versions). The old 3D Tools library has not been updated in many years, while the Helix Toolkit is continuously being improved.

Comment: I think its too big for me. I just need to draw lines and points (simple wireframes etc.). I will draw 3D on normal 2D controls by using simple projection.